# Pushing a file from within a apk

Tags: android

I want to be able to copy a file from within my apk to the sd-card and was just wondering if it was possible and how i would go about it as im struggling to find and infomation and the android chat rooms are all locked! Thanks in advance :)

Edit: I would like to push the file to the internal storage (prefrably /system/ but i can move it from the internal storage to there using terminal commands if needed)

Comment: Do you want to push the file when apk installed? Which file I mean from where? assets folder?

Comment: Once the apk is installed i want to push a txt file (I can store it wherever you need me to). This app is for rooted users if that helps with any console commands

Answer (score 4):

Put your file inside `assets` folder on your project, e.g. file.txt.

Get input stream to read the file:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt");
```

Copy the contents:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file.txt"))
byte[] buf = new byte[4096]
while (true) {
    int len = is.read(buf);
    if (len < 0) break;
    os.write(buf, 0, len);
}
os.close(); 
is.close();
```

Comment: Where about do i put the desired directory?

Comment: in your project create a new directory called asset

Comment: I mean how would i push it to a directory on internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

This is about how to push into **internal** storage http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal